# How to decrypt Vigenère ciphered text?

Tags: decryption, ciphers

The method I am using:
For example:  we have to decrpyt one message

```
         VVHQWVVRMHUSGJG
```

Step 1
Find the length

```
        VVHQWVVRMHUSGJG            --------- 1

         VVHQWVVRMHUSGJG           ----------2

          VVHQWVVRMHUSGJG          ----------3

           VVHQWVVRMHUSGJG         ----------4

            VVHQWVVRMHUSGJG        ----------5
```

We will find number of coincidences in b/w 1&2, 1&3, 1&4 and 1&5, so on till last letter.

I have calculated for the above ciphered it appears 4.

I assumed length of the key is 4.

Step 2 
Find each number in the key.

I confused here how we can calculate the each number, even if we know the letter frequency?

Comment: You can find a detailed cryptanalysis of the Vigenère cipher in Stinson: "Cryptography -- Theory and Practice", 3rd ed., Sect. 1.2.3.